# How can i mapp list of objects in the same class with same type

Tags: hibernate

```
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private list<Person> persons;

    public long getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPersons() {
      return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(String persons) {
      this.persons = persons;
    }
}
```

I want Hibernate OR Mapping with that above code please any one help to me. How can i add mapping to that person class (list of persons property).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would use a Set, instead of a List as duplicates are disallowed. Also, in your database table, you will need to have a Person_Id (Primary Key) and a Parent_Person_Id (Foreign Key that references the Person_Id PK). This will then ensure the relationship between a person (a parent) and a set of people (the children in the relationship). One example is that of a Manager and Employees. A manager is a Person and so is an Employee, but the manager manages many Employees and in this case the parent is the Manager and the Employees are children.

So your Person class would look like:

```
public class Person {
    // normal properties/attributes
    Set<Person> persons;

    // getters and setters
    // addPerson to the Set method
}
```

Then, you could use the following mapping:

```
<set name="persons" table="Person" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="false">
    <key column="person_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="xxx.Person" />
 </set>
```

However, what I have found is that the following [article](http://kruders.com/hibernate/hibernate-self-join-one-to-many-mapping/) may be of use to yourself in this matter given that you are trying to implement self-joins.